# Calender for Operating room Scheduler in Java Web appliaction

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing a jsp page where I need to add a calender for operating room in which I have to show time in Y axis and operating room in X axis

```
             OR1    OR2    OR3    OR4
```

7:00 am

7:15 am

7:30 am

7:45 am

can you please suggest the appropriate scheduler calender which I can use in this scenario.

I have checked icalender but not it is not working with my java 1.4 . I am using java 1.4 and weblogic 8.1 for this project.

Comment: Why are you using Java 1.4? Is there any good reason for it?

Comment: its for a very old project , and client does not want to migrate.

Comment: You might try to download the library sources (if possible) and build them for 1.4 bytecode. Not sure if it will work. Anyway, the more your client will delay the migration, the more will any change cost (time, money, nerves).